# Java- open a window from another class

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I tried a lot, but nothing works. I have to classes one is the main menu (opens a frame) and the other class (also a frame) should be open with a button in the main menu.

The ActionListner for the button (which should open the window from the other class) is implemented in the main menu code. Here:

```
Button btnopenRaum = new Button("show available rooms");
        btnopenRaum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {



                }

                catch(Exception e1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"failed");
                }
            }
        });
```

The class which implements the other JFrame is:

```
public class AvailableRooms extends GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AvailableRooms window = new AvailableRooms();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public AvailableRooms() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame(); ..
```

And my question is, how can I call the JFrame from the other class in my main menu class after clicking the button.

Thank you all in advance.